# Public URL to list all comments received on some user/channel?

Tags: youtube

The private link `https://www.youtube.com/comments`
lists the comments received and published on your videos ("you" = "logged user").

And the public link `https://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=...` lists the comments received on a particular video.

Is there some link to list the comments received on all the videos for some user/channel?

Comment: The title of the question says "my videos", but the last line says "some user/channel". Choose one and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way.

The all_comments link for individual videos also has been removed since this question was asked.